# Parsing delimited string in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would parse out a pipe delimited string in Python 3.0? My application is reading various barcodes in a random fashion. The barcodes are as below:

```
var = '07|415674|88881234564|3326'
```

I need to evaluate the length of each parsed variable and determine the one barcode I'm looking for.

Thanks for you help!
TC

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [split](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nothing came up on Google when you searched for 'parse a string in Python'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
values = '07|415674|88881234564|3326'
findLength = 4

for val in values.split("|"):
    if(len(val) == findLength):
        print("Found: " + val)
```

This splits the string on `|` and loops through the resulting array, checking the length of each value and printing it if it matches the `findLength` variable.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed...

Answer (score 1):

Using the string.split() method you can give it a delimiter to split on.  In this case

```
var.split('|')
```

will split var at every pipe and returns a list of strings